# Explanation request for the terminology and notation employed by Gauss in his major 1843/6 treatise on Geodesy

Tags: mathematics, geometry, gauss

**Background**:

In his 1827 treatise on differential geometry, Gauss in his "[theorema egregium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorema_Egregium)" proved that the curvature of a surface is an intrinsic invariant; it doesn't change under isometries of the surface (that is - bending and twisting is allowed, but no operation that distorts the original distances on the surface is allowed). This result became the cornerstone of the differential geometry of surfaces, but this is not the issue here. My question concerns the cartographic implication of this result - that one cannot draw a uniform scale map of a given surface on another, ***substantially different*** surface (for example, one cannot draw a uniform scale planar map of the spherical (or rather spheroidical) earth; there are inevitable distortions). As far as I understand, this is the motivation to Gauss's writing of his major two-parts treatise on Geodesy (which were published in the years 1843,1846) - which dealt with problems of conformal mappings (angle-preserving maps; conformal maps are necessary for navigation in long distances, since they represent angles of directions accurately) of the earth ellipsoid of revolution into a plane or a sphere.

**My question**:

According to Buhler's biography of Gauss:

> Part I of "Untersuchungen..." deals with the special case of the conformal mapping of an ellipsoid to a sphere; knowing this makes it possible to utilize ordinary spherical trigonometry for the purposes of geodesy. Small regions of the ellipsoid are mapped to the sphere by $$f(v)=\alpha v - i\mathbb{log}k$$ with $i$ the imaginary unit and $v$ an arbitrary point on the ellipsoid. The constants $\alpha$ and $k$ have to be chosen in a way such that the distortion of the original is minimized.

Obviously, I don't understand how Gauss arrived at this functional form of the mapping, but one thing that is already implied from this description is that Gauss's procedure is based on mapping ***small*** regions of the ellipsoid of revolution into a sphere, since a global mapping necessarily distorts distances (global mapping cannot be of uniform scale, as a consequence of the Theorema Egregium).

But already here I'm stuck - if we suppose $v$ to be a complex number, then how do we define a correspondence between points on the ellipsoid and the complex plane? Is it done via a stereographic projection? I looked into the beginning of Gauss's original paper and he doesn't give much more explanation about this formula, despite that apparently much of the treatise is based on this mapping. In addition, what does it mean that the constants $\alpha ,k$ are chosen such that the distortion is minimal? how to quantify distortion?

This lack of supporting explanations is a major obstacle to anyone willing to look into his work in Geodesy, but I'm sure that it might have a fairly simple explanation, since this publication was apparently very influential in the history of Geodesy (it is not an obscure, unpublished fragment).

***Useful links***:

- The treatise mentioned in this question is on p.259 of volume 4 of Gauss's works, here is a link: [Untersuchungen uber Gegenstande Der Hohern Geodesy](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN236005081?tify=%7B%22pages%22:%5B263%5D,%22panX%22:0.462,%22panY%22:0.446,%22view%22:%22toc%22,%22zoom%22:0.83%7D).